# How to make a Published property call map only when it receives data

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm pretty new in Combine, I'm trying to create a login flow where:

- When I click on the login button the app fires the GoogleSignIn `sign` function
- Then, when the session data is received on GoogleDelegate it needs to start a request to my server-side login method.

To do that I have a GoogleSignInController that controls the sign-in process:

```
class GoogleSignInController: GIDSignInDelegate {
    @Published var onSessionAcquired: GoogleSignInSessionData = ("", "")

    func signIn() {
        if (GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController == nil) {
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
        }
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
                print("The user has not signed in")
            } else {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            return
        }
        
        onSessionAcquired = GoogleSignInSessionData(idToken: user.authentication.idToken ?? "", serverAuthCode: user.serverAuthCode ?? "")
        
        print("Successful sign-in!")
        signedIn = true
    }
}
```

Then in the ViewModel, I'm using some states to control the process:

```
    static func whenStartedLogin() -> Feedback<State, Event> {
        Feedback { (state: State) -> AnyPublisher<Event, Never> in
            guard case .loadingGoogleSignIn = state else { return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher() }

            GoogleSignInController.shared.signIn()
            
            return GoogleSignInController.shared.$onSessionAcquired
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .map { Event.onGoogleSessionAcquired($0) }
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }

    static func whenReceivedGoogleSession() -> Feedback<State, Event> {
        Feedback { (state: State) -> AnyPublisher<Event, Never> in
            guard case let .loadingServerSession(googleSession) = state else { return Empty().eraseToAnyPublisher() }

            return self.signIn(idToken: googleSession.idToken, serverAuthCode: googleSession.serverAuthCode)
              .map { (userInfo, error) in
                  if let error = error {
                      return Event.onFailedToAcquireSession(error)
                  } else if let userInfo = userInfo {
                      return Event.onUserInfoAcquired(userInfo)
                  } else {
                      return Event.onFailedToAcquireSession(AppError.unknown)
                  }
              }
              .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
    }
```

The problem is: when I click on the login button, the `whenStatedLogin` function is fired, and it maps my event to be `Event.onGoogleSessionAcquired`. This should be mapped only when `onSessionAcquired` is changed (after the `sign` delegate is called). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out the solution for this problem. The correct data type to be used in my case is a `PassthroughSubject`.

```
let sessionSubject = PassthroughSubject<GoogleSignInSessionData, Never>()

...

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
            print("The user has not signed in")
        } else {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        return
    }
    
    sessionSubject.send(GoogleSignInSessionData(idToken: user.authentication.idToken ?? "", serverAuthCode: user.serverAuthCode ?? ""))
    
    print("Successful sign-in!")
    signedIn = true
}
```

Having it this way will make the map is called only when the subject receives an event.